# Basic java code to compare char of two strings

Tags: java, string, methods, char, compare

I want to write code that accepts two strings and returns the sum of the number of times when the char of both string does not match.

```
public int solution(String s1, String s2) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
        if (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i))
            sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This code of run when the length of the two strings are the same. I want to what I need to add to the code so that if the length of `string 1` > length of `string 2`, the code still run and also include the # char chat wasn't able to be compare to `string 2` because `string 2` is shorter. (vice versa)

ex:

```
s1: aaaaab
s2: ac

==> sum =5
```

or

```
s1: ab
s2: abbbb

==> sum = 3
```

Comment: `Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the min and max length of both string.

```
int min = 0, max = 0;
if(s1.length() > s2.length()) {
   max = s1.length();
   min = s2.length();
} else {
   min = s1.length();
   max = s2.length();
}
```

traverse only up to the minimum length

```
for (int i=0; i<min; i++){
   if (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) {
      sum++;
   }
}
```

then add the difference of max and min in the return value

```
 return sum + (max - min);
```

Answer (score 2):

The number you seek is a composite of 2 steps:

1. The number of differences between the strings from 0 to `Math.min(s1.length(),s2.length())` as you do it in your code.
2. The difference in length of both strings. `Math.abs(s1.length()-s2.length())`.

Add the numbers from (1) and (2) and it shall be the number thou seeketh ;)

Comment: since I am a complete beginner in java i don't really understand how i would add this to the code. It would be extremely helpful if you could elaborate more.